# Apache camel endpoints handling failures at startup

Tags: java, error-handling, apache-camel

I would like to build a high reliable service, so i need to handle every kind of network issues at a NATS endpoint;

1. startup exception, handling the exceptions at the startup, i noticed that if the server is not responding at startup the apche camel app exits..
2. handling reconnection after startup. So the defaul behavior is reconnecting every two seconds and i would like to overwrite it.

I am aware of  bridgeErrorHandler paramter, but it doesn't seem to work properly for this scenarios in fact int the following route:

```
errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()
            .maximumRedeliveries(5).redeliveryDelay(10000));
// receiving from NATS
from("nats:{{test_topic}}?bridgeErrorHandler=true")
 //and print it to system out via stream component         
 .errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler().maximumRedeliveries(5).redeliveryDelay(10000))
 .to("stream:out")
 .log("${body}");
```

The code's behavior is weird, it doesn't solve the 1. the app is exiting if NATS server is down, if the server goes down after the start up the default strategy is executed (2 seconds retry), ignoring my settings at route and context level.
How can i handle the point 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

For point 2, have you tried setting [reconnectTimeWait](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/nats-component.html#_endpoint_query_option_reconnectTimeWait) parameter? And for point 1, handling exceptions, may be you can try [exceptionHandler](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/nats-component.html#_endpoint_query_option_exceptionHandler)

Comment: if bridgeErrorHandler is enabled then exceptionHandler is not in use from the doc. I would like to handle the exceptions from my code to implement a different reconnection strategy not just reconnecting at fixed interval, so i was trying to avoid to use consumer settings as  reconnectTimeWait